# COUNTIFS - drag down, fill condition linearly:

Tags: excel, formula, countif

I need to drag this formula down and increase condition **5, (3rd argument)** in ASC: 5, 6, 7, 8... and keep everything else the same. Does anyone know how? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

=COUNTIFS(F$2:F$759772,5,J$2:J$759772,"Customer")

How original formula should increase:

=COUNTIFS(F$2:F$759772,5,J$2:J$759772,"Customer")

=COUNTIFS(F$2:F$759772,6,J$2:J$759772,"Customer")

=COUNTIFS(F$2:F$759772,7,J$2:J$759772,"Customer")

THANK YOU!

Paulo

Answer (score 0):

Criteria parameters are not meant to change as you drag a formula.  If that number is always increasing by one, you can use the row number to increase.

If your formula is entered into row 2 to being with, and your criteria needs to start with 5, then you can use:

```
=COUNTIFS(F$2:F$759772,ROW()+3,J$2:J$759772,"Customer")
```

Adjust ROW()+3 to match your worksheet layout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jody!
 I will use this option next time. I found an alternative last night to automate this by copying the column with all the station_numbers I wanted as a reference (removing all duplicates) and creating a column (N) with those numbers.

=COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$759772,N6,$J$2:$J$759772,"Customer", $E$2:$E$759772,1)

 I replaced parameter 5 with N6, which, when dragged down increments based on the referenced column; N7, N8.... There are over 400.000 rows in this spreadsheet. I appreciate your help!

Paulo